# How to take an integer input from a text field and add it to a value in a database

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm trying to create a banking interface and hence have asked the user to enter a withdrawing amount, which I need to subtract from the amount in the database.

`a` stores the value entered in the text field.
`c` needs to get the value stored in the database (seems to not be working).
`use.p1.gettext` is the password entered by the user to which I'm comparing.

```
int a=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankdetails","root","password");
   String Sql = "select * from users where password = "+use.p1.getText();
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(Sql);
   int c = rs.getInt("ball");
   int b=c-a;
   String sql = "insert into users(users,password,ball,s_ball) where password = password "+"value(?,?,?,?)";
   pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setInt(0,b);

   pst.execute();

   login_page page=new login_page();
   page.setVisible(true);
   page.getContentPane();
}
catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Try calling `rs.next()` before `rs.getInt`.

Comment: What happens if the user enters the password '';drop table users; ?

Comment: Also, insert into (...) where... is not valid SQL. Did you mean update?